# SSRS 2017 Line Up Multiple Tablix and Matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working in SSRS 2017. I have 3 sub reports, each with a USERID key that links them. The basic setup now is a master report with 1 tablix, it pulls a list of all USERIDs and then has 3 columns. Each column has sub report, 1 is a tablix and the other 2 are matrixs. When I run the report the USERID is passed to each of the sub reports and every USER ID has 2 rows, 1 for headers and 1 for data, but all 3 reports show correctly. What I am trying to do is make is it so the headers for each subreport only show on the first line or even better if they were in the true header of the Master Tablix. Code wise everything runs and works correctly. I am just trying to get the formatting to not list the headers 200 times. As a side, I am not committed to this architecture and if there is a better way to combine all these things I open. I tried combining all 3 into a single data set (unpivot the tablix and union the matrix) but then I lost all the formatting on the dates/currency etc.. I have also tried some hiding the header in the sub report with expressions, but since technically the report is only 1 line, anyway I hid it, it hides for all or none. 
Update: I have been able to combined the 2 matrixes into 1, then add columns with the tables, but each is a lookup so ...50 lookups. 
[image]

The above image shows the tablix with 1 matrix, as you see the headers are repeated for every group and they grow disproportionate so they cause with hidden rows. The 2nd matrix makes the issues multiple. The picutre below is the desired outcome, + one more matrix.

Comment: Share screen shot of issue you are facing and Expected output sample.

Comment: As @SoundappanA suggested, we need a bit of an example to help you. A few or all of these: example records, the source XML for the .rdl file, a picture of the issue and a picture of how you want it to look. You can use a GitHub site to store the .rdl file.

Comment: sorry I am trying to get an image, but i lost all my work and since i am fairly certain this is not possible in SSRs without customizing the XML, basically i think it's impossible to align to sub reports based on an account number, while maintaining headers on only the first line. Since technically the report is 1 line on every line, the headers always exist, also since they are subreports they can grow at different rates forcing excel to merge/hide rows.